# How do I properly keep my HTML elements contained in its parent view?

Tags: html, css, position, element, scaling

My webpage is divided into sections, each of which have an h1 headline. I have positioned the text at the top of each section where I see fit, however when I scale the window/screen size to a certain point, the text floats up and over laps the pervious section, like so:

**BEFORE SCALE BREAKING POINT**

[image]

**AFTER SCALE BREAKING POINT**

[image]

As you can see the text floats up to the pervious section after a certain scale point. Here is my HTML:

```
    <body>
      <div class="first-section">
        <h1>
          Dark,Darker,Darkest... Darker than Darkest... Darkest-est, whatever you get the point.
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="second-section">
        <h1>
          You must be looking at this guy, really weirded out... Well   guess what, so is he.
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="third-section">

      </div>
      <div class="fourth-section">

      </div>
    </body>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
/* Sections */

.first-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #6666FF;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/hallway.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.first-section h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFD700;
  font-size : 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: -200px;

}
.second-section {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: honeydew;
  background-image: url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/assets/awe.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
.second-section h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #FFD700;
  font-size : 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: -200px;
}
```

How do I stop the text from floating up out its parent section?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your top: -200px; ... you are positioning your h1 text out of the divs.

Could you provide a full example? What are you trying to achive?

Comment: yes i know, i only do that because i wanted to bring the text higher up on the section, it was smack in the middle, & i have more text to add.. & just look at the images in the question. I dont want the text to float up and overlap the previous section when i scale the window smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Change the CSS of your headlines to:

```
.second-section h1 {
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFD700;
  font-size : 6vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

It will then always be in the upper left position of the parent div.